# Any Recommedations for good video lectures on Django

Tags: django

I am starting out on using Django. I know the Django book is useful( http://www.djangobook.com/) but i would like to watch some video lectures first to start off. Any good recommedations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fresh out of Pycon 2012:

**[Introduction to Django](http://pyvideo.org/video/604/introduction-to-django)**

**[Django in Depth](http://pyvideo.org/video/610/django-in-depth)**

**[Django Form Processing Deep Dive](http://pyvideo.org/video/698/django-form-processing-deep-dive)**

Answer (score 2):

http://godjango.com/

> Each episode is focused on something that can help django developers do django development better. Most videos will be short, sweet, and to the point about the specific topic. It is expected that most developers have some experience with Django, but anyone will usually be able to benefit some how.